# Failing to create Quantlib's LM Fixed Volatility Model object

Tags: quantlib

I want to create am `LmFixedVolatilityModel` object as defined in http://www.jquantlib.com/en/latest/_static/javadocs/0.2.6-SNAPSHOT/jquantlib/index.html?org/jquantlib/pricingengines/swap/DiscountingSwapEngine.html

Below is my code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>

int main() 
{
    using namespace QuantLib;

    std::vector<QuantLib::Date> voldays;
    std::vector<QuantLib::Real> volvalues;

    voldays = TARGET().businessDayList(Date(29, March, 2019), Date(29, April, 2019));
    for (int i = 0; i < voldays.size(); i++) volvalues.push_back(0.10);

    ext::shared_ptr<LmVolatilityModel> volModel(new LmFixedVolatilityModel(volvalues, voldays);
}
```

However with this implementation, I am getting below error -

```
aa.cpp:17:50: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'QuantLib::LmFixedVolatilityModel'
        ext::shared_ptr<LmVolatilityModel> volModel(new LmFixedVolatilityModel(volvalues, voldays));
                                                        ^                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/ql/legacy/libormarketmodels/lmfixedvolmodel.hpp:33:9: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::vector<QuantLib::Real>'
      (aka 'vector<double>') to 'const QuantLib::Array' for 1st argument
        LmFixedVolatilityModel(const Array& volatilities,
        ^
/usr/local/include/ql/legacy/libormarketmodels/lmfixedvolmodel.hpp:31:11: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2
      were provided
    class LmFixedVolatilityModel : public LmVolatilityModel {
```

Could you please help me with the right way to create an `LmFixedVolatilityModel` object?

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: `volvalues` should be a `QuantLib::Array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not QuantLib installed at the moment, so I have no means to check the code below. However I could not resist posting this. Please verify whether it works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>

using namespace QuantLib;

int main() 
{
    std::vector<Date> voldays;
    std::vector<Real> volvalues(voldays.size(), 0.1);

    voldays = TARGET().businessDayList(Date(29, March, 2019), Date(29, April, 2019));
    
    Array volarray(volvalues.begin(), volvalues.end());    // added line

    ext::shared_ptr<LmVolatilityModel> volModel(new LmFixedVolatilityModel(volarray, voldays));

return 0;
}
```